# Import under path with Pika CDN?

Tags: javascript, cdn, snowpack

For example, RxJS main export are like this:

```
import { range } from "rxjs";
// Turns into
import { range } from "https://cdn.pika.dev/rxjs@^6.5.5";
```

But RxJS operators are under `rxjs/operators`. How can I import these files?

Thanks!!